# Why is part of my CSS code missing in Safari but not chrome?

Tags: html, css, safari

I've been working on a website. I've noticed that half of my CSS code is missing when I try to use Safari. But I don't have this issue when I load the code on Chrome.
The odd thing is that I can't reproduce the issue when I open the HTML file on my Mac but when I go to my website, some CSS styling is missing.

I'm hosting my website on godaddy and using Plesk as file system.

I checked csslint.net and it found no errors with my CSS code.

Orignial CSS:

```
/*custome css*/
.center{
   text-align: center; 
}
.row{
    padding-top:10px;
}
.Fundamental-grid{
    padding: 10px;
}
.center-ul{
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}
.center-icon{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #9db5ed;
}
.div-vertical-align{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.intro-div{
    background-color: #B4C6F0;
}
body{
    padding-top:70px;
    background-color: #edf0f5;
    font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', serif;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
h3{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

What I see in Safari when I inspect sources:

```
center {
    text-align: center;
}

.row {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.container {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.Fundamental-grid {
    padding: 10px;
}

.center-ul {
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}

.center-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reordering your css and seeing if the problem is tied to the h1 definition, or if perhaps it is a problem with the rule that precedes it? Have you tried loading the css file directly in the browser and seeing what is displayed? You didn't mention in the question if you had cleared the browser's cache, did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your browser's cache. If that doesn't work then visit the website with a random query string, that means add `?someRandomCharacters` at the end of the URL. If your URL is `example.com`, visit `example.com?pevnuiyrmo`.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response.
I checked the browsers again today and the issue was gone. It was probably the cache because this only happened on my device. 
I'm pretty new to web development so still don't fully know the basics.